# Decrypt and move rc4 encrypted password to Wordpress wp_user table?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, encryption, passwords, rc4-cipher

I have [RC4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) encrypted data stored in a MySQL table that I need to move to the wp_user table and store as a Wordpress encrypted password. These are passwords so I'd prefer to move them securely, but I'm open to any suggestion.

This data was originally stored from a custom built Wordpress user management plugin that we've lost the developers for. Now we are attempting to move the users over to a Wishlist Member solution which stores them as regular wordpress users. I want to be able to change out the system without having to ask all the users to reset their passwords.

The old user data is encrypted as a hashed password concatenated with the encryption key. Below is the code sample that decrypts the secure data. I have the encryption key,

```
$secure_data = unserialize(
    rc4crypt::decrypt(
        $this->data->password . OLD::ENCRYPT_KEY,
        $this->data->secure_data)
    );
```

Any suggestions on how can I move this data into `user_pass` of `wp_users`?

Comment: You can't unencrypt hashed password. Encryption <> hashing

Comment: @gbn But RC4 is a cipher, not a hash function. This is of course an extremely silly way to store passwords.

Comment: Read up on the standards of passwords and what representations thereof to store. That should put you on the right track.